# LSB confirm startup script won't start apache tomcat on ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, startup-scripts, lsb

I want to start my tomcat server automatically on startup. Therefore I retrieved a simple LSB conform script from the net and modified it to my needs. This is the script:

```
# Provide logging functions like log_success_msg, log_failure_msg and log_warning_msg
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

[ -f /etc/default/rcS ] && . /etc/default/rcS
PATH=/opt/jdk1.7.0_21:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39

case "$1" in
  start)
        /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/startup.sh
        ;;
  stop)
    /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/shutdown.sh
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
        ;;
  status)
        ;;
  *)
        log_failure_msg "Usage: {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}"
                exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Now, I copied it to /etc/init.d and applied a "chmod +x tomcat" on it. Then I tried to run it

```
/etc/init.d # ./tomcat start
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/startup.sh: 1: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/startup.sh: uname: not found
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/startup.sh: 1: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/bin/startup.sh: dirname: not found
Cannot find /catalina.sh
The file is absent or does not have execute permission
This file is needed to run this program
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

These

> uname: not found
>   dirname: not found

show that you're missing a proper PATH.

Try changing the PATH line in your startup script to:
`PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/jdk1.7.0_21:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39`

Answer (score 1):

THis is the issue

PATH=/opt/jdk1.7.0_21:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39

You forgot to append $PATH to that.. it must be

PATH=/opt/jdk1.7.0_21:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.39:$PATH